# How to register eureka-clients with eureka-server on different hosts. Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I'm running my eureka-server on my localhost. I'm able to register all my other on localhost running services and everthing works like expected.

Now I want to register a service which is running on a linux machine. My properties looks like that:

```
spring.application.name=myService-service
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://myMachine.domain.lan:8888
server.port=8002
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://myMachine.domain.lan:8761/eureka/
```

But the service is not able to register on eureka server on localhost. (At the end its the same service which runs on localhost)

I get those exceptions:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
```

But I'm able to get my configuration files from my config-service running on localhost.

**Which configurations do I need to register my service to eureka from linux machine(client) to localhost(server)?**

This annotations do I use:

Service:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableEurekaClient
public class MyServiceApplication {
```

Eureka-Server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServiceApplication {
```

P.S.:Also the opposit way is not working. Means having eureka server on linux machine and the services on localhost. Get the same exceptions.

**Edit1:**

Eureka-Server properties:

```
spring.application.name=eureka-service
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://myMachine.domain.lan:8888
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.instance.hostname=KBHWS242.myDomain.lan
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```

**Edit2:**

testsrv is the linux machine. (172.25.82.108)

```
2016-08-31 09:17:01.912  INFO 27105 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
2016-08-31 09:17:01.919  INFO 27105 --- [           main] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2016-08-31 09:17:01.923  INFO 27105 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1472627821923 with initial instances count: 0
2016-08-31 09:17:02.068  INFO 27105 --- [           main] c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : Registering application reservation-service with eureka with status UP
2016-08-31 09:17:02.070  INFO 27105 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1472627822070, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2016-08-31 09:17:02.073  INFO 27105 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_RESERVATION-SERVICE/testsrv1.myDomain.lan:reservation-service:8002: registering service...
2016-08-31 09:17:02.173 ERROR 27105 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused


2016-08-31 09:17:02.174  WARN 27105 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failure
2016-08-31 09:17:02.175  WARN 27105 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_RESERVATION-SERVICE/testsrv1.myDomain.lan:reservation-service:8002 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server


2016-08-31 09:17:02.175  WARN 27105 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server

2016-08-31 09:17:02.594  INFO 27105 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8002 (http)
2016-08-31 09:17:02.596  INFO 27105 --- [           main] c.n.e.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration : Updating port to 8002
2016-08-31 09:17:04.134  INFO 27105 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-08-31 09:17:04.659  INFO 27105 --- [           main] a.e.ReservationServiceApplication        : Started ReservationServiceApplication in 44.893 seconds (JVM running for 47.272)
2016-08-31 09:17:31.913  INFO 27105 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2016-08-31 09:17:31.914  INFO 27105 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2016-08-31 09:17:31.914  INFO 27105 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2016-08-31 09:17:31.914  INFO 27105 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2016-08-31 09:17:31.914  INFO 27105 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2016-08-31 09:17:31.914  INFO 27105 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2016-08-31 09:17:31.914  INFO 27105 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2016-08-31 09:17:31.917 ERROR 27105 --- [freshExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

2016-08-31 09:17:31.917  WARN 27105 --- [freshExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failure
2016-08-31 09:17:31.918 ERROR 27105 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_RESERVATION-SERVICE/testsrv1.myDomain.lan:reservation-service:8002 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server

2016-08-31 09:17:31.924 ERROR 27105 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

DiscoveryClient_RESERVATION-SERVICE/testsrv1.myDomain.lan:reservation-service:8002 - was unable to send heartbeat!
```

**Edit3:**

Dependencies:

```
Maven: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:1.1.1.RELEASE
Maven: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:1.1.2.RELEASE
Maven: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:1.1.1.RELEASE
Maven: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-core:1.1.5.RELEASE
Maven: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:1.1.5.RELEASE
Maven: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:1.1.1.RELEASE
Maven: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-archaius:1.1.5.RELEASE
Maven: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:1.1.3.RELEASE
Maven: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka:1.1.5.RELEASE
Maven: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-ribbon:1.1.5.RELEASE


Maven: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server:1.1.5.RELEASE
```

Comment: shouldnt url to eureka ends with /discovery/eureka?

Comment: @freakman in the most post I read it was without /discovery, But got same result using /discovery. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you actually binding the eurake server to the correct IP? Could be that it is only bound to `localhost` instead of all ips. Can you actually access that URL from anymachine other then your local machine...

Comment: @M.Deinum I am able to get the configuration of my config server from linux to localhost. So this works. I'm also able to make a http call to `http://172.25.82.108:8761/` and get the eureka dashboard. And I also think of that there is just a server-config for localhost. But this is exactly the issue I have. Added my server-properties.

Comment: config and eureka are 2 seperate services so the fact that you can access one doesn't mean you can access the other. Have you tried using the IP instead of the hostname of your machine for connecting. Also where do you try `http://172.25.82.108:8761/` if that is from the same machine as that has the IP address you aren't testing anything. for the `eureka.instance.hostname` try the actual hostname (instead of the ip-address).

Comment: @M.Deinum Tried with the IP but got same result. I made a wget from the linux machine to the dashboard of eureka running on my localhost. That was ok. I also tried with with hostname for the `eureka.instance.hostname` but got same result. Added more of the exception trace.

Comment: `eureka.instance.preferIpAddress: true`

`eureka.instance.ip-address: 172.25.82.108`

`eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://{eureka server ip}:{eureka server port}/eureka/`

Maybe you try this?

Comment: @nurgasemetey on client or server?

Comment: @Patrick on client

Comment: @Patrick, you should also give ip and port eureka server. I intentionally left them unassigned.

Comment: @nurgasemetey sorry, does not work. Do you have any other suggestions. Or can you give a full config file for server and client?

Comment: What about version of `spring cloud` do you use?

Comment: @nurgasemetey updated question

Comment: I thought that there is version clash. I suggest you to ask from https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud or open issue in github.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After changing `.properties` to `.yml` file of one of my service and corrected misspelling of `defaultZone` everything works like expected.

Comment: defaultZone is valid point. btw for me it worked with .properties file as well