# Spring EurekaClient in container can't register to EurekaServer on localhost nor EurekaServer in docker container

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm developing a project using Spring Boot Cloud with Eureka. When i run everything on my machine everything works fine. But when I start using Docker:

- if I put EurekaServer in Docker container and run it, all services on localhost can register to it
- if I put a service in Docker container and run it, it cant't register to neither EurekaServer running on localhost nor EurekaServer running in Docker container

I also have Cloud Config Server running on localhost:8888 and services in Docker container cant access it.
Tried running it all in docker-compose, docker stack, none of it works.

bootstrap.yml for Eureka Server:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: conhub-eureka-server   
  cloud:
    config:
      uri:
      - http://localhost:8888 
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

Dockerfile for Eureka server (I use fabric8 docker maven plugin):

```
FROM openjdk
VOLUME /tmp
ADD maven/conhub-eureka-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar myapp.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /myapp.jar'
EXPOSE 8761
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","- 
 jar","/myapp.jar"]
```

bootstrap.yml for example service (it's a zuul gateway):

```
server:
  port: 8765
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: http://localhost:8888
  application:
    name: conhub-gateway
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://${EUREKA_SERVER_HOST:localhost}:8761/eureka
```

Dockerfile for example service:

```
FROM openjdk

VOLUME /tmp
ADD maven/conhub-gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar myapp.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /myapp.jar'
EXPOSE 8765
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","- 
 jar","/myapp.jar"]
```

I've read many posts here and tried everything but with no success.
I guess my biggest surprise is why a service in a container can't access in my case http://localhost:8888 for configs? I can easily access it manually.

**EDIT 2**
Well I finally found the mistake. In a EurekaClient the proper way of writing delault zone for EurekaServer is:
**defaultZone** not **default-zone**. 
Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242635/how-to-register-eureka-clients-with-eureka-server-on-different-hosts-spring-boo)